# subprocess.call is extending filepath

Tags: python, subprocess

I have ran into a most unsettling issue. First off, I have a file that runs nmap and uses argparse to get the options for the test. From the script I am working on, I am using subprocess.call to run this nmap script with the appropriate options. I'm in the correct directory and am attempting to call this other nmap script with this command

In this case, `hosts = scanme.nmap.org, expected = sample\scanme.nmap.org.xml, 
custom_args = '-sS '`

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'NmapProject\run_nmap.py',
                 '-e', expected, '-cA', custom_args, hosts])
```

yields to the following error,

```
  File "NmapProject\run_nmap.py", line 215, in main
    host_data.expected_dict = _expected_ports_to_dict(ET.parse(exp_path), host_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample\\scanme.nmap.org.xml\\scanme.nmap.org.xml'
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why scanme.nmap.org.xml is getting appending to "sample\scanme.nmap.org.xml"? Running the run_nmap.py script on its own works fine. I'm truly flustered as to why this occurring. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: That depends purely on your `run_nmap.py` script and how it builds its internal path to the XML.

Comment: Yea I'm starting to figure that out. I guess the brightside of this is that I'll be best friends with my debugger when all is through

Comment: To be very clear, **`subprocess.call()` doesn't expand anything**. You can determine what the argv actually is via procfs; `readarray -d '' args </proc/"$pid"/cmdline; declare -p args` will work, if `pid` is the PID of your `run_nmap.py`. Do be sure you're actually assigning your variables from constant strings to be sure or actually printing them at runtime to be sure you aren't mistaken about the runtime values.

Comment: For anyone other than you to solve this problem, what we'd need is a [mcve] -- the shortest possible self-contained code we can run without changes to see the problem ourselves. See "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/ for guidance on creating such an example.